# Steps for Using JavaBuilder with Java

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

Can any one please tell me what are the steps for using JavaBuilder; to actually using Matlab Functions; with Java.

I've tried using JavaBuilder using its examples but I got the error as::

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the library mclmcrrt713.dll, required by MATLAB Builder JA, on java.library.path.
 This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MCR, its absence may indicate an issue with that installation or the current path configuration.
The MCR version that this component is trying to use is: 7.13.
```

What am I suppose to do to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matlab support has a page about this, it might help you.

[Why do I receive an error regarding missing mclmcrrt7x.dll when I run my stand-alone application compiled with MATLAB Compiler?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1IW46N/)

Comment: Even after setting the path, I got the same error that Failed to find the library mclmcrrt713.dll.

Comment: Did you check if you have the right version of the compiler installed?

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, sorry. It's difficult to solve problems like this without access to the computer in question.

Comment: actually settings were right. The problem was that I was suppose to restart the netbeans after setting the path variable..

Thanx for your help.. :)